# concatenating two tables relative many objects in cell

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've a problem with a connection between two tables. And more specifically I've a first table (Df_1), which has a column 'B' and tree rows. In each row in column 'B', I have a cell with three values (nine values in column B in three rows), precisely, each cell has an array with three values. In addition, I have two columns with single values.

In the second table, I have nine rows. And the column "name" which has data that are the same as in the first frame in column "B". But here they are divided, each for different rows.

I assume I need the first frame, change it to have nine lines. In the sense of these vectors I have to break. And then connect the two frames to this new column in the first frame and the "name" columns in the second frame.

This is first frame with three rows:

```
Df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
              'A': ['White','Black','Yellow'],
              'B': [['lamp','bed','wardrobe'],['sink','glass','towel'],['kitchen','toilet','room']],
              'C': [4,2,9]
               })
```

This is second frame with nine rows:

```
Df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Number' :['six','one','nine','ten','four','five','two','three','nine'],
               'Name': ['lamp','bed','wardrobe','sink','glass','towel','kitchen','toilet','room'],
               'Description': ['large','small','loud','weak','loyal','loyal','loud','large','small']})
```

And this is third frame, which is basic on the first and second frames.

```
Df_3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['white','white','white','Black','Black','Black','Yellow','Yellow','Yellow'],
              'Name': ['lamp','bed','wardrobe','sink','glass','towel','kitchen','toilet','room'],
              'C': [4,4,4,2,2,2,9,9,9],
              'Description': ['large','small','loud','weak','loyal','loyal','loud','large','small']
              })
```

Comment: Can you post an example of how you want your join to look like? It is a bit unclear from the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone knows a more efficient way, but you could just brute force it and use a loop.

```
temp_list = []

for index,row in Df_1.iterrows():
    for e in row['B']:
        temp_list.append((row['A'],row['C'],e))

temp_df = pd.DataFrame(temp_list,columns = ['A','C','B'])

Df_3 = Df_2.merge(temp_df, left_on = 'Name',right_on = 'B')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

**Explode Df_1**

Use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html), quite useful in this context

```
#Intermediate step to unpack column B

intermediate_df = pd.concat([Df_1.drop('B', axis='columns'), pd.DataFrame(Df_1.B.values.tolist(), index=Df_1.index, columns=['B1', 'B2', 'B3'])], axis=1)
intermediate_df

    A       C   B1       B2      B3
0   White   4   lamp     bed     wardrobe
1   Black   2   sink     glass   towel
2   Yellow  9   kitchen  toilet  room

Df_1_final = Df_1_extended.melt(id_vars=['A', 'C'], value_name='Type')
Df_1_final

    A       C   variable    Type
0   White   4   B1          lamp
1   Black   2   B1          sink
2   Yellow  9   B1          kitchen
3   White   4   B2          bed
4   Black   2   B2          glass
5   Yellow  9   B2          toilet
6   White   4   B3          wardrobe
7   Black   2   B3          towel
8   Yellow  9   B3          room
```

**Merge into Df_2**

Then you just need to merge Df_1_final into Df_2 using [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), selecting the desired columns

```
final_df = Df_2.merge(Df_1_final, left_on=['Name'], right_on=['type']).loc[:, ['A', 'Name', 'C', 'Description']]
```

Which yields exactly the same as Df_3

```
final_df

    A       Name      C     Description
0   White   lamp      4     large
1   White   bed       4     small
2   White   wardrobe  4     loud
3   Black   sink      2     weak
4   Black   glass     2     loyal
5   Black   towel     2     loyal
6   Yellow  kitchen   9     loud
7   Yellow  toilet    9     large
8   Yellow  room      9     small
```